# Как передать параметры при вызове метода call в Bitrix 24?

Tags: php, битрикс24

Мне надо вывести задачи по фильтру, делаю как у них в документации написано:

```
$result = CRestCurrent::call('task.item.list', array("FILTER" => array("TITLE" => 'Создать первую задачу')));
```

Пытаюсь отфильтровать задачу по названию, мне выводится список всех задач почему-то.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я вот битрикс этот в глаза не видел ни разу, но открываем [доки](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/tasks/task/item/list.php) и видим  красным написано

1. Внимание! Метод устарел и не поддерживается. Рекомендуется использовать методы `tasks.task.*`.
2. Внимание! Для метода `task.item.list` обязательно нужно указывать сортировку для фильтрации. **Фильтрация без сортировки возвращает все задачи.**

и если на первое еще можно закрыть глаза, то второе явно вам говорит, почему ваш метод не работает.

Comment: Нде, кринж конечно, проглядел.